# How to get the value by a key from a super nested Json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, linq

```
"_embedded": {
"cscaia:status_report": {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "title": "status_report",
      "name": "status_report",
      "href": "https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg/status_report"
    },
    "type": {
      "href": "https://diaas-dev.gtaia-test-domain.net/std-dev-lux-13100/insurance/schemas/quotes/statusReportDocument"
    },
    "up": {
      "href": "https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg"
    }
  },
  "consistent": false,
  "messages": [
    {
      "message": "Incomplete attribute",
      "context": [
        {
          "propertyNames": [
            "quote$distributor_id"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "severity": "error",
      "code": "incomplete_attr"
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Here I need to find out the value of the key "severity" but i don't know the level of it .I don't have the key for its parent as well inside which it is nested as the json will always be dynamic.

I have tried with an extension method. But for nested key i am not getting the result.

```
public static TType JsonValue<TType>(this JObject obj, string key)
    {
        object result = null; //default to null if nothing is found

        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            var token = item;

            if (token.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                result = token.Value.ToObject<TType>(); //return the value found
                break;
            }

            if (!obj[token.Key].Children().Any())
                continue;

            var jt = obj[token.Key].ToString();

            if (!jt.StartsWith("["))
            {
                result = JsonValue<TType>(JObject.Parse(jt), key);
            }
            else
            {
                obj[token.Key].Children().ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    //only the first match will be returned
                    result = JsonValue<TType>(JObject.Parse(x.ToString()), key);
                });
            }

            if (result != null)
                break;
        }
        return (TType)result;
    }
```

Comment: what you are trying to do is it in JS or C# both are opposite

Comment: I tried in c# but if you could give the solution in js also its fine.@user7417866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and return if a value is found.

```js
function getValue(object, key) {
    var value;

    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
    if (key in object) return object[key];

    Object.values(object).some(v => {
        value = getValue(v, key)
        return value !== undefined;
    });    

    return value;
}

var data = { _embedded: { "cscaia:status_report": { _links: { self: { title: "status_report", name: "status_report", href: "https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg/status_report" }, type: { href: "https://diaas-dev.gtaia-test-domain.net/std-dev-lux-13100/insurance/schemas/quotes/statusReportDocument" }, up: { href: "https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg" } }, consistent: false, messages: [{ message: "Incomplete attribute", context: [{ propertyNames: ["quote$distributor_id"] }], severity: "error", code: "incomplete_attr" }] } } };

console.log(getValue(data, 'severity'));
console.log(getValue(data, 'href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to achieve this using `C#` you could try querying all descendends using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` untill you find the right Property.

This should work ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ni7r9E)):

```
public static T GetJsonPropertyValue<T>(string json, string property)
{
    var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
    var token = parsedJson.Descendants()
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == JTokenType.Property
            && ((JProperty)t).Name == property);
    return token is JProperty
        ? token.First().Value<T>()
        : token.Value<T>();
}
```

From your example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = @"{
     ""_embedded"": {
        ""cscaia:status_report"": {
            ""_links"": {
                ""self"": {
                    ""title"": ""status_report"",
                    ""name"": ""status_report"",
                    ""href"": ""https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg/status_report""
                },
                ""type"": {
                    ""href"": ""https://diaas-dev.gtaia-test-domain.net/std-dev-lux-13100/insurance/schemas/quotes/statusReportDocument""
                },
                ""up"": {
                    ""href"": ""https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg""
                }
            },
            ""consistent"": false,
            ""messages"": [
                {
                    ""message"": ""Incomplete attribute"",
                    ""context"": [
                        {
                            ""propertyNames"": [
                                ""quote$distributor_id""
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    ""severity"": ""error"",
                    ""code"": ""incomplete_attr""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}";
    var context = GetJsonPropertyValue<dynamic>(json, "context");
    var severity = GetJsonPropertyValue<string>(json, "severity");
    Console.WriteLine(severity);
    Console.WriteLine(context);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Getting an error stating that Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.

Comment: So you are having a severity property with a nested object? It works assuming it’s a simple key string value property like your example. Eventually post the Json that gives you the error.

Comment: Please find the link for the json .for which i am facing issue.https://xfl.jp/tvBEai

Comment: I am not sure what you adjusted, but the above method works well with your json file. Here is the [demonstration](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O1Uab9)

Comment: Use the key  postal_address$address_category and try its throwing an exception .

Comment: it wasn't clear from your question that you try to query nested objects by key, not just key value properties as stated in the title. I have updated the answer and the demo.

Comment: Yaa its look good now but the problem is if the key holding an array i want to skip it.If the key has a value directly than return the value."Key":"Value" "Key":{"message":"some value"}(Not Required)

Comment: You should try to ask a complete question from beginning on, including all requirements, instead of adding edge cases via comments later on. The above method returns the converted value directly if the key has one value, if it's a nested object, it will return the aggregate. As such it answers the above question.
The answer you marked doesn't handle any of your later requirments and throws an error if queried for `postal_address$address_category`, besides the fact that you asked for a `C#` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a recursive function to run through all level.

```js
var _embedded = {
  "cscaia:status_report": {
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "title": "status_report",
        "name": "status_report",
        "href": "https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg/status_report"
      },
      "type": {
        "href": "https://diaas-dev.gtaia-test-domain.net/std-dev-lux-13100/insurance/schemas/quotes/statusReportDocument"
      },
      "up": {
        "href": "https://api.dxc-dev-aia.hub-1.dev.us.insurance.dxc.com/quotes/ID-mrMxY1Dg"
      }
    },
    "consistent": false,
    "messages": [
      {
        "message": "Incomplete attribute",
        "context": [
          {
            "propertyNames": [
              "quote$distributor_id"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "severity": "error",
        "code": "incomplete_attr"
      }
    ]
  }
}

function recursive_search (object) {

  let output = null;

  //check if object is an array or object
  if (Array.isArray (object)) {
  
    //check every array-element recursive
    for (let i in object)
      output = recursive_search (object[i])

  } else
  if (typeof object === 'object') {
  
    //get all keys of object
    let keys = Object.keys (object);
    
    //check every key if it is 'serverity'. if not check every property recursive 
    for (let i in keys)
      if (keys[i] === 'severity') {
      
        output = object[keys[i]];
        break;
      
      } else
      if (typeof object === 'object')
        output = recursive_search (object[keys[i]])
  
  }
  
  return output;

}

//get serverity
serverity = recursive_search (_embedded)

console.log ('serverity = ' + serverity);
```