# How to get the value by a key from a dynamic super nested Json?

Tags: c#

JSON Link https://www.filesend.jp/l/en-US/tvBEai

I have a dynamic nested json. I have key using key i need to find out the value from json.
N:B The parent node of the key i am not aware.
Please refer the link if i pass a key if that key is present inside the json at any level it should return the value.

I have tried with below code but didn't get the result.

```
public static TType JsonValue<TType>(this JObject obj, string key)
{
    object result = null; //default to null if nothing is found

    foreach (var item in obj)
    {
        var token = item;

        if (token.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            result = token.Value.ToObject<TType>(); //return the value found
            break;
        }

        if (!obj[token.Key].Children().Any())
            continue;

        var jt = obj[token.Key].ToString();

        if (!jt.StartsWith("["))
        {
            result = JsonValue<TType>(JObject.Parse(jt), key);
        }
        else
        {
            obj[token.Key].Children().ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                //only the first match will be returned
                result = JsonValue<TType>(JObject.Parse(x.ToString()), key);
            });
        }

        if (result != null)
            break;
    }
    return (TType)result;
}
```

Comment: maybe it is worth to try XPath expression? expecially  if you have dynamic json with no schema

Comment: Cannot download the JSON file

Comment: https://xfl.jp/tvBEai Try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value by a key from a super nested Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098991/how-to-get-the-value-by-a-key-from-a-super-nested-json)

Comment: Where is the difference to [your other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098991/how-to-get-the-value-by-a-key-from-a-super-nested-json)?